# Windows Server Time Incorrect After Updates/Reboot

Tags: windows, batch-file, time, server, windows-server-2012

We're running Windows Server 2012 R2. I've found that when the server installs updates and restarts (at 4am daily) it will restart in the incorrect time zone. Our time size is EST -5 (currently -4 with Daylight Savings), and the server defaults to UTC -0, which is 4 hours ahead of our time zone.

When we originally discovered the issue we found that the only workaround that actually worked was to use the task scheduler to run a sync command when the server restarted. That task and command worked well until two weeks ago, around 6/15/2017, and since then it hasn't worked. I've reviewed the task/event logs and it claims to have run successfully, yet it hasn't.

My only thought at this point is that there was something in the Windows update that rendered the sync code useless. But I'm at a loss for what that could be. Does anyone have suggestions about how to identify the problem?

The sync code we are using is in a .bat file. The two Windows updates installed on the morning of 6/14, which I suspect could be the cause of the task no longer working, are:

2017-06 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64-based Systems (KB4022726)

Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool for Windows 8, 8.1, 10 and Windows Server 2012, 2012 R2, 2016 x64 Edition - June 2017 (KB890830)

```
REM *** Retry for up to 15 minutes (90 retries @ 10 seconds each)
set retryCount=0

:SyncStart
if %retryCount == 90 goto SyncEnd
set /A retryCount=retryCount + 1

REM *** Resync the system clock
net start w32time
w32tm /resync
if errorlevel 1 goto SyncDelay
if errorlevel 0 goto SyncEnd

:SyncDelay
REM *** If unsuccessful, delay 10 seconds, then retry
choice /n /t:y,10>nul
goto SyncStart

:SyncEnd
```

Comment: The time zone definitely does not change by installing an application or security update. But the time zone setting is account related. So it is possible that configured for your account is time zone EST but for system account UTC time zone. It is possible with administrator privileges to copy the region (country, date/time/currency format, etc.), language (keyboard, speech recognition, etc) and time settings (time zone, daylight saving time adjustment, etc.) of current user to default user account (for new accounts) and system account. You should make use of this possibility.

Answer (score 1):

The batch file contains a syntax error in line:

```
if %retryCount == 90 goto SyncEnd
```

The value of an environment variables must be referenced with `%VariableName%` on using standard expansion and not just `%VariableName` like a **FOR** loop variable (`%I` on cmd respectively `%%I` in a batch file) or a batch file argument (`%0`,`%1`, ...), or with `!VariableName!` on using delayed expansion which is not needed here.

The code could be also optimized:

```
@echo off
REM *** Retry for up to 15 minutes (90 retries @ 10 seconds each)
set retryCount=0

:SyncStart
if %retryCount% == 90 goto :EOF
set /A retryCount+=1

REM *** Resync the system clock
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe start w32time
%SystemRoot%\System32\w32tm.exe /resync
if not errorlevel 1 goto :EOF

REM *** If unsuccessful, delay 10 seconds, then retry
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe 10 /nobreak
goto SyncStart
```

Well, the code can be optimized even more:

```
@echo off
REM *** Retry for up to 15 minutes (90 retries @ 10 seconds each)
set retryCount=0
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe start w32time
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe 5 /nobreak

:SyncTime
%SystemRoot%\System32\w32tm.exe /resync
if not errorlevel 1 goto :EOF

REM *** If unsuccessful, delay 10 seconds, then retry
set /A retryCount+=1
if not %retryCount% == 90 %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe 10 /nobreak & goto SyncTime
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `net /?`
- `net start /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `timeout /?`
- `w32tm /?`

And read the Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576).

Comment: Stellar answer. Thank you. I should point out I didn't write the command, it's way out of my league. I just assumed something "broke" it since it worked for 8+ months until 6/14. Since it stopped working immediately after the server installed updates I just assumed they were related.

Comment: Your solution had been working, but now it has stopped. I've included a picture of the log showing the sync task as complete, but without the time correctly updating. Any ideas on what may have caused it to stop working? [link](https://s.nimbus.everhelper.me/share/1312613/c6db4lh153m93m666xtg)

Comment: The batch file must be executed with elevated privileges as an administrator. The batch file just sends the Windows Time Management the message to force a resynchronization with configured time source. The configured time source is usually the NTP server of Microsoft and time synchronization is done with built-in NTP client of Windows. So you have to check if the configured NTP server is working and does not deny the request from NTP client to resynchronize. See in Windows registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time` and read about this registry key.